Microsoft Form - Weekly trigger and reminder
I want one MS form to be sent every Monday of week to set of people and save response of that form at common place once someone submitted it.
However, if anyone fails to submit it by Wednesday then I want to trigger the reminder email.
I read about Microsoft Power platform but did not find any informative details to get this done.
Anyone have any idea, how can I implement this mechanism?

You can create a flow in Power Automate, which is part of the Power Platform. Begin with a list of all individuals who should respond, then review it weekly and send an email. Next, construct a flow that activates upon receiving a new response and updates the entry in your list. You will then have a list of non-respondents and can set up a recurring flow to contact everyone left on the list every Wednesday.
